# Print index from array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on a text-based game, and I want to print the results in the end.
However, at the moment it only prints the latest input data and not the 5 loops in the array.

This is my array

```
int[] turnarr = new int[5];

turnarr[x] = turn;

for (int i = 0; i < turnarr.Length; i++)
     Console.WriteLine(turnarr[i] + "\t" );
```

Comment: Do you ever put other values into your turnarr or just at turn[x] = turn?

Comment: what is the x and .. sorry i dont see any input data..., is that turn the input data.. the sure you have only one item initialized other are 0

Comment: I have an turn++ so every time the game loops it's adding another turn. How can I give X another value ?
@  Shekhar_Pro exactly whats happend when I print, it get 0 for the rest of the print.

Comment: Any chance you could add in a sample output? May clairify things a bit.... i.e. are you seeing `0 0 0 0 51` or `51 51 51 51 51` or `51`

Comment: This it what it prints. As you se the first row is turn 5, and the data in turn 5 is the lastest data input.
Turn  Wind      Monkey    Distance
5       -3 ms   100m            86 meter
-Resultat---
Turn  Wind      Monkey    Distance

0       0 ms    100m            86 meter
------------------------------Resultat---
Turn  Wind      Monkey    Distance

0       0 ms    100m            86 meter
----------Resultat---
Turn  Wind      Monkey    Distance

0       0 ms    100m            86 meter
--Resultat---
Omgång  Vinden  Apan    Avstånd från apan

0       0 ms    100m            86 meter

Comment: @ deepee Sorry for my latest post. It didn't make any sence =|. But its printing 5 0 0 0 0

@ Mark Avenius The value of X is Zero but i have an turn++ so it ad 1 more on every loop

Comment: is `int[] turnarr = new int[5];` inside the same loop you have `turn++`. If so, Guffa has it nailed your problem. YOu are instantiating the array on every loop. This will clear the array and only set the current turn's value. To test the theory just move `int[] turnarr = new int[5];` outside of the loop it is in... perhaps outside of the method entirely and sitting as a field in your class to at least test this theory.

Comment: @deppee1, I totally agree with you and Guffa, but I dont really seem to find the problem, I tryed to move the turnarr outside the loop, but It didnt help, I understand that my array is beeing reset every time it loops.
Well I did a pastebin of my code, If someone have some time over to look it up

http://pastebin.com/iLqazWim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your pastebin and tracked the issue down I believe:

The following line:

`Console.WriteLine(turnarr[i] + "\t" + windarr[i] + " ms \t" + apmeterarr[x] + "m\t\t" + lenghtarr[x] + " meter\t\t");`

you are using i for 2 spots, and x for the other 2 for your index variable...

Change
`apmeterarr[x]` and
`lenghtarr[x]`

To
`apmeterarr[i]` and
`lenghtarr[i]`

Comment: Thank you deepee1, that was another problem that i had :)

The main problem in my loop was that I didnt add an x++; so my array didn't know what to save :)Well we are all beginners sometimes Thank you all guys for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be certain, as I only see part of the code, but I suspect that you are recreating the `turnarr` array in each turn, which would make every entry except the last one zero.

Comment: its hard to play a guess game here but the for loop has no braces so it seems that console line is the only line in the loop so he couldn't be reinitializing the array .. whatever the value of x is we will have 0 printed for rest...

Comment: @Shekhar_pro: I don't suggest that he is recreating the array in each iteration in loop that displays it, but in the code for the turns that puts the data in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If the value of `x` never changes then you're only writing to a single item in the array, and thus overwriting it every time with the latest value of `turn`.

Answer (score 1):

If `turn` is your last turn value, and `x` is 4, you will see four zeroes on their own lines and then the value of `turn` because you are only assigning to the `x`th index of `turnarr`

Comment: Not blank lines, as an integer variable can't be null, but zero values.